# Instantiating rosjava messages faster for PointClouds

Tags: ros, message, rosjava, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there a way to generate/instantiate messages faster in rosjava (newest rev)? From my knowledge i have to use a messageFactory.

Point32 p = messageFactory.newFromType(Point32._TYPE);

The problem is that it's too slow if you have to have generate a lot of Points32 for a PointCloud message. I narrowed it down to this bottleneck.

I tested it with my older rosjava builds (December 2011) and there you instantiate messages directly and i don't have any speed problems.

EDIT1: I have seen that PointCloud2 offers an byte array which should solve the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57381/instantiating-rosjava-messages-faster-for-pointclouds/) by [Kircheis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4373/kircheis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using PointCloud2 is the correct solution.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2